# equi integrablity

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

[See page 5 here](http://myreader.toile-libre.org/uploads/My_5351765aab1b7.pdf). Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions, $f_n \in L^1(\Omega)$, which is bounded in $L^1(\Omega)$ ($f_n \in L^1(\Omega)$), i.e., $|f_n|\leq C$ with $C$ a constant which does not depend on $n$.
How we can prove that $(f_n)$ is equi-integrable, i.e. $\forall \eta > 0, \exists \delta > 0: |S| \leq \delta \Rightarrow\displaystyle\int_{S} |f_n| dx \leq \eta\text{ for all } n$?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Are there finitely many $f_n$? If not, are there any additional assumptions on $f_n$? It's false as stated.

Comment: How do you mean by finitely many $f_n$? there is an sequence. and i edit my post. Help me please

Comment: It is not true that an arbitrary sequence $\{f_n\}$ of $L^1(\Omega)$ functions is equi-integrable. If the set of functions is *finite*, it's true (or if some additional assumptions are imposed); what do you mean by "she is bounded in $L^1(\Omega)$"?

Comment: It's bounded by an function $h \in L^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: So you mean that there is an $h \in L^1(\Omega)$ such that $|f_n(x)| \le h(x)$ for almost every $x$? (This is not equivalent to being bounded in $L^1$.)

Comment: $|g_n|\leq C$ with $C$ an constant not depend to $n$

Comment: Please [edit] your original question, then, to include all the assumptions needed.

Comment: I edit my post with all assumptions i have.

Answer (score 1):

Well your definition of being bounded in $L^1(\Omega)$ is strange, but with this one, and if $|\Omega|$ refers to the measure of $\Omega$, then you just have

$\int_{\Omega}|f_n|dx \leq \int_{\Omega}Cdx \leq |\Omega|C$ so $\delta=\frac{\eta}{C}$ works well...

If your definition of being bounded in $L^1$ is the usual one, id est $sup_{f_n}\int_{\Omega}|f_n|dx < \infty$ then I don't think the theorem is true without further assumptions.

Comment: Right, it's quite false with the usual definition of $L^1$-boundedness: Rescaling a single function to have a larger peak and smaller support gives easy counterexamples. What the OP was thinking of is boundedness in the space $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: Are you undestand french? because the corse where i find the problem is in french. i joint the document in my first post and the problem is in the page 4.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see anything speaking about equi-integrability on page 4...do you speak about the final lemma on page 5 ?

Comment: Yes, i speak about the final lemma on page 5. To applied it, we have to prouve that $g_{\epsilon}$ is equi integrable. So how we can prouve it please?

Comment: I'll take a look, but at first sight it should use the definition of $g_{\epsilon}$, and not just the fact that it is bounded in $L^1$. Because the ATTENTION section says that with some hypothesis, it's not enough to derive the convergence of $f^{\epsilon}$. But if being bounded implied being equi-integrable, then with the following lemma, the ATTENTION section would be false because from its hypothesis you would have the equi-integrability, and then with the lemma, you'd have the convergence. Hence equi-integrability of $g_{\epsilon}$ must come from elsewhere

Comment: @ubon is $g$ considered to be $L^1$ in the proof ?

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand. How we can prouve that $g_e$ defined in p4 is equi integrble?